# Table/images to display

Tags: love2d

I created a table in love2D and want the images to display when I start my game, However, I am having difficulty trying to work out which code I would need to write in function love.draw section to get them to display?

```
sprites[1] = {image = love.graphics.newImage("example.jpg"),x= 10,y=100}
sprites[2] = {image1 = love.graphics.newImage("example.jpg"),x= 10,y=50}
```

Comment: Could you provide more of you code? For some context?

Answer (score 0):

Function you are looking for is [`love.graphics.draw`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw). It takes any [`Drawable`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Drawable) as an argument. This includes [`Image`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Image).

An example would look like:

```lua
function love.load ()
   sprites = {}
   sprites[1] = {image = love.graphics.newImage("example.jpg"), x = 10, y = 100}
   sprites[2] = {image = love.graphics.newImage("example.jpg"), x = 10, y = 50}
   --            ^^^^^ Removed "1" from "image1" to make table consistent.
end

function love.draw ()
   for i, v in ipairs(sprites) do
      love.graphics.draw(v.image, v.x, v.y)
   end
end
```

I encourage you to read one of the beginner tutorials [listed in the wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/Category:Tutorials). For instance: [Simple Game Tutorials](https://simplegametutorials.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

```
img = 1
x = 2,
y = 3

function love.load ()
   sprites = {
     {love.graphics.newImage("example1.jpg"), 10, 20 },
     {love.graphics.newImage("example2.jpg"), 20, 30 },
     {love.graphics.newImage("example3.jpg"), 30, 40 },
   }
end

function love.draw ()
   for _ = 1, #sprites do
      local sprite = sprites[_]
      love.graphics.draw(sprite[img], sprite[x], sprite[y]) 
   end
end
```